# 1D scalar wave equation PML finite difference implementation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Following Steven G. Johnson's excellent PML (perfectly matched layer - an
absorbing boundary condition)
[tutorial](http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.369/pml.pdf), I came-up with the
following implementation of a PML for the 1D scalar wave equation using finite
differences:

Scalar wave equation:
\begin{equation}
u_{xx}(x, t) = \frac{u_{tt}(x, t)}{c^2(x)} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where subscripts indicate partial differentiation, so $u_{xx}$ is the second
partial differential of $u$ in space.

Split (1) into:
\begin{equation}
\phi_t(x,t) = u_x(x,t)\tag{2a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t) = c^2(x) \phi_x(x,t)\tag{2b}
\end{equation}

Verification:
\begin{equation}
\mbox{$x$ partial derivative of (2a): } \phi_{xt}(x,t) = u_{xx}(x,t)\tag{3a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mbox{$t$ partial derivative of (2b): } u_{tt} = c^2(x) \phi_{xt}(x,t)\tag{3b}
\end{equation}
substitute (3a) in (3b): $u_{tt}(x,t) = c^2(x) u_{xx}(x,t)$, which is (1).

For the PML region, we use the wavefield at
$x' = x + i \frac{f(x)}{\omega}$ (where $\omega$ is angular frequency), as
this will exponentially
damp the wavefield.

Making this change of coordinates, and with $\sigma(x) = f_x(x)$, $u_x(x,t)$
is replaced by $\frac{u_x(x',t)}{1 + i \frac{\sigma(x)}{\omega}}$.

Applying this to (2):
\begin{equation}
\phi_t(x',t) = \frac{u_x(x',t)}{1 + i \frac{\sigma(x)}{\omega}}\tag{4a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_t(x',t) = c^2(x)\frac{\phi_x(x',t)}{1 + i\frac{\sigma(x)}{\omega}}.\tag{4b}
\end{equation}
($c(x')=c(x)$ and $\sigma(x')=\sigma(x)$)

Assuming that $u$ and $\phi$ can be written in the form
$A e^{i(kx - \omega t)}$, $u_t = -i\omega u$. Applying
this to (4) and multiplying both sides by the denominator
of the right hand sides:
\begin{equation}
(1 + i \frac{\sigma(x)}{\omega}) (-i\omega) \phi(x',t) = u_x\tag{5a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(1 + i\frac{\sigma(x)}{\omega}) (-i\omega) u = c^2(x)\phi_x(x',t)\tag{5a}
\end{equation}

Multiplying,
\begin{equation}
(1 + i\frac{\sigma(x)}{\omega}) (-i\omega) = -i\omega + \sigma(x).
\end{equation}
Using this in (5), and noting that $-i\omega u = u_t$,
\begin{equation}
\phi_t(x',t) = u_x(x',t) - \sigma(x)\phi(x',t)\tag{6a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_t(x',t) = c^2(x)\phi_x(x',t) - \sigma(x)u(x',t)\tag{6b}
\end{equation}

Taking the $x$ partial derivative of (6a), the $t$ partial derivative
of (6b), and substituting, as in (3), we get
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}(x',t) = c^2(x)(u_{xx}(x',t) - (\sigma(x)\phi(x',t))_x) -
\sigma(x)u_t(x',t)\tag{7}
\end{equation}

Expanding the derivative $(\sigma(x)\phi(x',t))_x$ using the product rule:
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}(x',t) = c^2(x)(u_{xx}(x',t) - (\sigma_x(x)\phi(x',t) +
\sigma(x)\phi_x(x',t))) - \sigma(x)u_t(x',t)\tag{8}
\end{equation}

Using central differences for $u_{tt}$ and $u_t$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{u(x',t+1) - 2u(x',t) + u(x',t-1)}{\Delta t^2} = c^2(x)(u_{xx}(x',t) -
(\sigma_x(x)\phi(x',t) + \sigma(x)\phi_x(x',t))) - \sigma(x)\frac{u(x',t+1) -
u(x',t-1)}{2\Delta t}
\end{equation}

Rearranging:
\begin{equation}
u(x',t+1) = \frac{c^2(x)\Delta t^2}{1 + \Delta t\frac{\sigma(x)}{2}}(u_{xx}(x',t) -
(\sigma_x(x)\phi(x',t) + \sigma(x)\phi_x(x',t))) + \Delta t
\sigma(x)\frac{u(x',t-1)}{2 + \Delta t\sigma(x)} + \frac{2u(x',t) - u(x',t-1)}{1 +
\Delta t \frac{\sigma(x)}{2}}\tag{9}
\end{equation}

Using a forward difference for $\phi_t$ in (6a):
\begin{equation}
\frac{\phi(x',t+1) - \phi(x',t)}{\Delta t} = u_x(x',t) - \sigma(x)\phi(t),
\end{equation}

Rearranging:
\begin{equation}
\phi(x',t+1) = \Delta t u_x(x',t) + \phi(x',t) (1 - \Delta t \sigma(x))\tag{10}
\end{equation}

(9) shows how to update $u$, and (10) shows how to update $\phi$.

This seems to work fairly well, but I noticed that the implementation in PySIT
seems to be a bit
[different](https://github.com/pysit/pysit/blob/master/pysit/solvers/constant_density_acoustic/time/scalar/constant_density_acoustic_time_scalar_1D_4.h).

In my notation, I believe the PySIT version would be written:
\begin{equation}
u(x',t+1) = \frac{c^2(x)\Delta t^2}{1 + \Delta t\frac{\sigma(x)}{2}}
(u_{xx}(x',t) + \phi_x(x',t)) + 
\Delta t\sigma(x)\frac{u(x',t-1)}{2 + \Delta t\sigma(x)} + 
\frac{2u(x',t) - u(x',t-1)}{1 + \Delta t \frac{\sigma(x)}{2}}\tag{11}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\phi(x',t+1) = -\Delta t \sigma(x) u_x(x',t) + \phi(x',t) (1 - \Delta t \sigma(x))\tag{12}
\end{equation}

These are close to my own, but there are some discrepancies that trouble me:

- In (11), there is a $+ \phi_x(x',t)$ term instead of $-(\sigma_x(x)\phi(x',t) +
    \sigma(x)\phi_x(x',t))$ (compared to (9))
- In (12), $u_x$ is multiplied by $-\sigma$ (compared to (10))

The PySIT implementation seems to work as well, and has the advantages of
$\phi$ being zero outside the PML region (where $\sigma=0$, so we can just use
the regular wave equation there and avoid calculating $\phi$), and also not
requiring $\sigma_x$.

How does my derivation need to be altered to arrive at the PySIT equations?

Comment: There is something in your derivations that does not seem right. The change of variables $x'=x+\mathrm{i} f(x)/\omega$ and the chain rule, tells me


\begin{eqnarray*}
  u_x = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}
   \frac{d x'}{d x} =
   u_{x'} \left (1 + \frac{\mathrm{i} f'(x)}{\omega} \right )
   \quad , \quad 
   \phi_{x} = 
  \phi_{x'} \left (1 + \frac{\mathrm{i} f'(x)}{\omega} \right )
\end{eqnarray*}
But you have the factor $\left ( 1 + \frac{\mathrm{i} f'(x)}{\omega} \right )$ dividing. Why?

Comment: I believe I know what is going on in my previous comment. The original system is the wave equation in the complex plane with an analytic (continuation) solution in the points $(x',t)$ where $x'=x+if'(x)/\omega$ is a complex number. We want to find the corresponding equation in terms of the real (no complex) variable $x$.  Then $u_{x'}=u_x/(1 + \mathrm{i} f'(x)/\omega)$.